# Spark: saveAsTextFile() only creating SUCCESS file and no part file when writing to local filesystem

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am writing an RDD to a file using below command:

```
rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile(FilePath)
```

When the FilePath is HDFS path (`hdfs://node:9000/folder/`) everything works fine.

When the FilePath is local path (`file:///home/user/folder/`) everything seems to work. The output folder is created and `SUCCESS` file is also present.

However I do not see any `part-00000` file containing the output. There is no other file. There is no error in the spark console output either.

I also tried calling collect on the RDD before calling `saveAsTextFile()`, giving `777 permission` to output folder but nothing is working.

Please help.

Comment: same problem here. Any updates?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46812960/result-of-transformation-on-an-empty-rdd/46842042#46842042 for answer

Comment: can you confirm whats the value for `spark.master` config?

Answer (score 1):

save to local make effects only when using `local` master

Answer (score 0):

In order to save a Spark object to the local driver filesystem, you'll need to use `collect()`, then open a file yourself to write that collection into.

Otherwise, if you ran as part of a YARN job, for example, you should go look at the local filesystems of the nodemanagers where the Spark job ran