# Result of transformation on an Empty RDD

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I have an RDD(combinerRDD)on which I applied below transformation

```
    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = combinerRDD.mapToPair(
            new PairFunction<Tuple2<LongWritable, Text>, String, Integer>() {
                String filename;
                Integer count;
                Message message;

                @Override
                public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(Tuple2<LongWritable, Text> tuple) throws Exception {
                    xlhrCount = 0;
                    filename = "";

                        filename = "New_File";
                        for (JobStep js : message.getJobStep()) {
                            if (js.getStepName().equals(StepName.NEW_STEP)) {
                                count += 1;
                            }
                        }

                    return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(filename, xlhrCount);
                }
            }).reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
                               @Override
                               public Integer call(Integer count1, Integer count2) throws Exception {
                                   return (count1 + count2);
                               }
                           }
    );
```

My question is when `combinerRDD` has some data inside, I get right result .But when `combinerRDD` is empty the result written into HDFS is only an empty _SUCCESS file . I was expecting 2 files in the case of transformation on an empty RDD ie _SUCCESS and empty part-00000 file .Am I right? How many output files should I get .

I reason why I am asking this is because I got different result in 2 clusters , the code ran on cluster 1 resulted in _SUCCESS file and cluster 2 resulted in _SUCCESS and empty part-00000 . I am confused now . Is the result dependent on any cluster setup?

Note : I am doing a left join on `newRDD.leftOuterJoin(combinerRDD)`, which gives me no result(when combinerRDD has only _SUCCESS) and newRDD contains value .

Answer (score 0):

Ok,so I found a solution. I am using spark-1.3.0, which has below issue: ie. a left outer join with an emptyRDD gives empty result .

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9236

I was creating empty Pair RDD like below:

```
JavaRDD<Tuple2<LongWritable, Text>> emptyRDD = context.emptyRDD();
myRDD = JavaPairRDD.fromJavaRDD(emptyRDD);
```

Now using :

```
List<Tuple2<LongWritable, Text>> data = Arrays.asList();
JavaRDD<Tuple2<LongWritable, Text>> emptyRDD = context.parallelize(data);
myRDD = JavaPairRDD.fromJavaRDD(emptyRDD);
```

It works now, ie my RDD is no more empty. Fix is available in versions: 
1.3.2, 1.4.2, 1.5.0 (reference above link).